# oracle, join with special requests

Tags: oracle, join, view

I have three tables with articles, inventory and warehouse.

```
CREATE TABLE "ARTICLE" 
(   "ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
)

CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" 
(   "ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "ARTICLE_ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER(9,0),
    "WAREHOUSE_ID" NUMBER(9,0)
)

CREATE TABLE "WAREHOUSE" 
(   "ID" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
)
```

I created a view, with shows me all inventory (with article name, etc.)

```
CREATE VIEW "INVENTORY_VIEW" AS
a.ID AS A_ID,
a.NAME AS A_NAME,
i.ID AS I_ID,
i.QUANTITY AS I_QUANTITY,
i.WAREHOUSE_ID AS I_WAREHOUSE_ID
FROM
 ARTICLE a
LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTORY i ON i.ARTICLE_ID = a.ID
```

I did it to make sure, I get a row for each article, even if there's no row in inventory. (I_WAREHOUSE_ID is null in that special case)
This works fine except for one case:

As soon as there is one row in INVENTORY for another warehouse of course the row (with I_WAREHOUSE_ID = null) disapears for the other warehouses.
(The other warehouses (e.g. Warehouse 2) select the inventory by "WHERE I_WAREHOUSE_ID=2" or "I_WAREHOUSE_ID is null".)

Anybody an idea how to solve this?
What I need is a article row for each WAREHOUSE_ID (with ID) if there is no iventory row for this article and warehouse.
My idea was to create a second view with all article / warehouse combinations and then kind of join that table with the inventory, but I had no success.

Comment: If you're filtering on `warehouse_id = 2` why would you want to include articles which aren't in that warehouse's inventory?

Comment: the article table is for both warehouses. If there is no inventory row available, I want to show at least one row with no stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want one result row per article and warehouse. So cross join the two tables and outer join the inventory then:

```
CREATE VIEW inventory_view AS
SELECT
  a.id AS article_id,
  a.name AS article_name,
  i.id AS inventory_id,
  i.quantity AS inventory_quantity,
  w.id AS warehouse_id
FROM ARTICLE a
CORSS JOIN WAREHOUSE w
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory i ON i.article_id = a.id AND i.warehouse_id = w.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you asked (pls next time post expected result in tabular text) you could try following query:

```
SELECT
A.ID AS A_ID,
A.NAME AS A_NAME,
I.ID AS I_ID,
I.QUANTITY AS I_QUANTITY,
I.WAREHOUSE_ID AS I_WAREHOUSE_ID
, W2.NAME
, W2.ID
FROM ARTICLE A
LEFT JOIN INVENTORY I ON I.ARTICLE_ID = A.ID 
CROSS JOIN WAREHOUSE W2
WHERE I.WAREHOUSE_ID IS NULL OR (W2.ID IS NOT NULL AND I.WAREHOUSE_ID=W2.ID);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO ARTICLE VALUES (1,'PROD_A');
INSERT INTO ARTICLE VALUES (2,'PROD_B');
INSERT INTO INVENTORY VALUES (1, 1,10,2);
INSERT INTO "WAREHOUSE" VALUES (1,'WA');
INSERT INTO "WAREHOUSE" VALUES (2,'WB');
```

Output:

```
+------+--------+------+------------+----------------+------+----+
| A_ID | A_NAME | I_ID | I_QUANTITY | I_WAREHOUSE_ID | NAME | ID |
+------+--------+------+------------+----------------+------+----+
|    1 | PROD_A | 1    | 10         | 2              | WB   |  2 |
|    2 | PROD_B | NULL | NULL       | NULL           | WA   |  1 |
|    2 | PROD_B | NULL | NULL       | NULL           | WB   |  2 |
+------+--------+------+------------+----------------+------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not posting a result table. In this case, one row is missing. I also want the row with ArticleId 1 (Prod_A) with Warehouse WA (ID 1).

Comment: You can change WHERE condition, or see Thorsten answer